# Exponential equation has no solutions

Tags: calculus

> Prove that the equation:
> $$5^x + 6^{\frac{1}{x}} + 7^{\frac{1}{x} + x} = 58$$
> has no solutions over the reals.

I have observed the graph of the function in Desmos Graph Calculator has am just above $59$ (actually around $60$) thus not reaching $58$, but I can't really quantify it. I have done a search on approach0 [(Search Results Here)](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%245%5Ex%2B6%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%7D%2B7%5E%7Bx%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%7D%3D58%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ano%2C%20OR%20content%3Asolutions&p=1) and the only thing related is a post on AoPS where the answerer is trying only to guess solutions to simillar problem [(AoPS Thread Here)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1713459p11060163).

[image: Graph on Desmos]

Comment: It's easy enough to see the equation can have no negative solutions.  Try taking the $\ln$ of the left-hand side and finding the extremum of the resulting function.

Comment: Depending on the context of the problem (and making some guesses based on what you've posted), one approach could be to show that the expression on the LHS is $ \geq 59$, hence cannot be equal to 58. $\quad$ I'm not sure why you put ENT or Diophantine equations as tags here. Are you looking for integer solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sketch of a proof:

1. If $x<0$, then $f(x) = 5^x + 6^{1/x} + 7^{x+1/x} < 5^0 + 6^0 + 7^0 = 3$;
2. If $x>0$, then $6^{1/x} > 5^{1/x}$, so $f(x) > g(x) = 5^x + 5^{1/x} + 7^{x+1/x}$;
3. $g'(x) = \left(5^x -\frac{1}{x^2} 5^{1/x}\right)\ln 5 + \left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) 7^{x+1/x}\ln 7$ has a zero at $x=1$;
4. $g''(x)> 0$ for all $x>0$, hence $x=1$ is the only zero of $g(x)$ in $(0,\infty)$;
5. $g''(1) > 0$, therefore $g(x)$ has a minimum at $x=1$;
6. From $2$ and $5$ it follows that $f(x)>g(1)=59$ in $(0,\infty)$;
7. From $1$ and $6$ we conclude that $f(x)\neq 58$ for all $x\in{\mathbb R}\setminus\{0\}$.